# Cannot install Varnish 3.x on CentOs 7

Tags: centos, yum, varnish, centos7

I have a freshly installed Centos7 and I wish to install Varnish 3.0; according with https://www.varnish-cache.org/installation/redhat I have installed the repo varnish-3.0.el6.rpm but ...

```
[root@reverse ~]# yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="varnish-3.0"   install varnish
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package varnish.x86_64 0:3.0.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: varnish-libs = 3.0.7-1.el6 for package:   varnish-3.0.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnishapi.so.1(LIBVARNISHAPI_1.0)(64bit) for package: varnish-3.0.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: varnish-3.0.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libvarnishapi.so.1()(64bit) for package: varnish-3.0.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package varnish.x86_64 0:3.0.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: varnish-3.0.7-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package varnish-libs.x86_64 0:3.0.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: varnish-libs-3.0.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: varnish-3.0.7-1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
       Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: varnish-libs-3.0.7-1.el6.x86_64 (varnish-3.0)
       Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try again without the "disablerepo" argument.

Comment: Sorry @AndréDaniel but ``yum --enablerepo="varnish-3.0" info varnish`` grabs the epel version (which is 4.x and I need 3.x), so I have to al least disable epel and in this way it does not work.

Comment: What about installing libpcre beforehand (without disabling any repos) and then installing Varnish again using your command ?

Comment: pcre is installed by default. 

    ```# locate libpcre```

    /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1
    /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.0
    /usr/lib64/libpcre16.so.0
    /usr/lib64/libpcre16.so.0.2.0
    /usr/lib64/libpcre32.so.0
    /usr/lib64/libpcre32.so.0.0.0
    /usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0
    /usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
    /usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0
    /usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to install packages meant for EL6 onto EL7. This will not work and there is no way to make it work. They are *not* compatible.

If you really want to run an *old* Varnish version, then use EL6 to begin with. The version of varnish included with EPEL for EL7 is 4.0, so it is not likely there will ever be 3.0 built for EL7.